# Why is this jquery in visualforce not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

This code is in visualforce (salesforce's page editor language). Basically the apex:repeat tags function as a sort of loop, generating a set of urls from outputlink. All these urls have a class of "name".

What the jquery is to do is find all the urls with the class name, and click them so they open in new windows. Its not working.

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Account" extensions="maininvoice">

<apex:repeat value="{!theListOfIDs}" var="anId">
     <apex:outputLink target="_blank" value="{!URLFOR($Page.invoice2,anId)}" styleClass="name" />
</apex:repeat>

<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jquery, 'js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js')}"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
j$(document).ready(function(){

$('.name').click();
alert("debug");
                }
                );

</script>

</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2):

A [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) won't cause the default behavior to occur  (e.g. following the link/opening a window), if you want that to happen, you'll have to call [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.open) yourself, like this:

```
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
j$(function(){
  $('.name').each(function() {
    window.open(this.href);
  });
  alert("debug");
});
```

Note though, most browsers will block you from doing this, not sure what to recommend there, and I'd personally dislike opening windows on page load as well.

Comment: Right thanks for the reply but thats not even working. Is there anything else you can suggest perhaps a workaround

Comment: It will work with "j$('.name').each(function()" - note the "j" in the front. A minor typo. I've tested it in Salesforce but I won't post code in answer as the reputation should go to Nick :)